# Ant - How to remove the leading or trailing spaces from the values in the properties file?

Tags: ant

I'm quite new to Ant and I need help in figuring out how to remove the spaces from the values in the properties file. I have 2 files namely, build.xml and build.properties.

**build.xml**

```
<target name="info">
      <echo>You are at ${sitename}</echo>
</target>
```

**build.properties**

```
# Website Name
sitename=   www.stackoverflow.com
```

When I now execute the Ant, I want the leading spaces before 'www' to be removed. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In properties files, the spaces after the `=` in `sitename=` are [already ignored](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.Reader-):

> ...if the first non-white space character after the key is '=' or ':',
>   then it is ignored and any white space characters after it are also
>   skipped.

Trailing whitespace can be handled by reading the properties file with `<loadproperties>` and then using a `<trim>` nested under a `<filterchain>`...

### Script

```
<loadproperties srcFile="build.properties">
    <filterchain>
        <tokenfilter>
            <trim/>
        </tokenfilter>
    </filterchain>
</loadproperties>
<echo>sitename: |${sitename}|</echo>
```

### Output

```
 [echo] sitename: |www.stackoverflow.com|
```